# is react-native-navigation works on react-native-web app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I have react-native project and I am using react-native-navigation, now I want to give support for web, is react-native-navigation work on react native web?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean react-navigation? (https://reactnavigation.org/)? If you want to use react-navigation check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/web-support.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, please read the docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/web-support/